# Trying to adjust the numbers for the horizontal axis of a plot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have some data (32 points) which corresponds to elements along an artificial transmission line of a fixed distance. The plot in its current form is shown below:

[image: ListLinePlot of data]

What I am trying to do is make the numbers along the horizontal axis map to a range of [0,1] instead of [0,32]. Since the spacing between the data points cannot be changed, I was wondering how I might go about changing the Tick marks.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Look at the examples given under Examples > Options > DataRange in the documentation article on [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

Comment: Or provide the data as {x,y} pairs.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Sin[Pi/32 Range@32]
ListPlot[data, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it resolved my issue.